# Jquery click not being bound

Tags: jquery

I have some html appended using handlebars, but am unable to get the event from a hyperlink to fire:

JS - this code is called during document.ready.

```
$(".media-item a.meddelete").unbind("click");
$(".media-item a.meddelete").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("assetid");
    alert(id);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="media-item">
   <p><a href="ImageManipulation.aspx">Edit</a></p>
   <p><a href="#" class="meddelete">Delete</a></p>
</div>
```

I can't see what is wrong, any ideas?

Comment: Does the binding happen before or after the HTML is injected?

Comment: Handlebars will also be running at `document.ready()` so the above html will not exist until after that.  The 2 answers below, using 'on()' & delegation will fix this problem.  If they do not work then there is something else wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by 'injected' you mean that the elements in your example are appended to the DOM dynamically after the page has loaded, you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.media-item a.meddelete', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data("assetid");
    alert(id);
});
```

Note that `document` in my example should be changed to be the nearest static element for best performance.

Comment: Its not appended as such, its 'put' into the dom somewhere between the start and end. Will your code example still work?

Comment: It will. You should use this method (delegated events) to hook to any element which is created after the page was loaded.

Comment: Worked like a charm, as you suggested I bound this to the div that holds the appended element.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$(".media-item a.meddelete").click(function (event) {
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".media-item a.meddelete", function (event) {
```

If you're dynamically adding elements to the page, you need to use jQuery's event delegation syntax.

Comment: Thanks, what's the difference, as I copied from another piece of code that works that is doen like above?

Comment: The syntax you used in your question will work for elements that already exist at the time the code is executed. The code I posted will work for any elements that exist at the time the code was executed, as well as any new matching elements that are dynamically added later.